# Background img based on Current Month

Tags: php, css, background

Using php, how would I make my the background image on my website change based on the current month??

January = 01.jpg

Febuary = 02.jpg

etc....

Currently I am using "rotator.php" in a separate directory to get a different image with each refresh.

css file I have this:

body

{

background: url(../images/theme/backdrop/rotator.php);

which links to the rotator.php obviously.... I wanted to replace the rotator.php with index.php but am not sure what to use for code to get it to call up the images.

This is what I have so far....

```
 <?php


 // Image File Ext.

$extList = array();
$extList['gif'] = 'image/gif';
$extList['jpg'] = 'image/jpeg';
$extList['jpeg'] = 'image/jpeg';
$extList['png'] = 'image/png';

//today and Image to use per today

$today = date('m');
printf('$today');

if ($today == 01) {
    $image = "01.jpg";
}
elseif ($today == 02) {
    $image = "02.jpg";
}
elseif ($today == 03) {
    $image = "03.jpg";
}
elseif ($today == 04) {
    $image = "04.jpg";
}
elseif ($today == 05) {
    $image = "05.jpg";
}
elseif ($today == 06) {
    $image = "06.jpg";
}
elseif ($today == 07) {
    $image = "07.jpg";
}
elseif ($today == 08) {
    $image = "08.jpg";
}
elseif ($today == 09) {
    $image = "09.jpg";
}
elseif ($today == 10) {
    $image = "10.jpg";
}
elseif ($today == 11) {
    $image = "11.jpg";
}
elseif($today == 12) {
    $image = "12.jpg";
}

?>
```

Not sure if this is going in the right direction....

Comment: Why do you have a java tag?

Comment: Lots of different possible solutions. Do you have code samples of what you have tried so far?

Comment: **Hint**: `$month = date("m");`

Comment: PHP has a `date()` function:  http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: You're confusing the assignment operator `=` with the equality operator `==` - your `if` statements all need to be in the form of `if ($month == 01)`, otherwise it will always choose the first option.

Comment: I tried the == portion and still no dice...??

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the easy things:

```
printf('<html class="month-%s">', date('m'));
```

And in the CSS then:

```
body {background: /* default background style */}
    .month-01 body {background-image: url('01.jpg')}
    .month-02 body {background-image: url('02.jpg')}
    ...
```

This allows you not only to style the body but also every other element on your website based on the month.

Comment: Check the code I attempted above... let me know where I am wrong.... I think I need something to get the month....

Comment: @C.Smith: Why that complicated? Can't you change the class attribute of the HTML? That is much more effective (and you likely want to cache your CSS in the long run).

Comment: Usuing a Simple Machines Forum as my base, just trying to manipulate what is already there to get the desired effect the file you see above is what I have attempted on my own... I directed the css file in the theme of the system to look for the above file... letting me control the desired background from the php created.... I think... lol

Comment: printf('<html class="month-%s">', date('m')); <<= Where would I put this bit of code ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you have yourself set up, but the easiest way that comes to mind is to link a php file as your stylesheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.php" />
```

And on styles.php

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css");
?>
body {
  background: url('<?= date('m') ?>.jpg'); // 'm' is number month (01 through 12) 
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: I have index.css which links to the rotator.php in the image directory.... was going to use index.php in the directory to make it choose the right image....

Comment: You mean you have something like this?
`background: url('rotator.php');`

If so, you need rotator.php to pass the proper headers for the image format you want to use.

Comment: body

{

background: url(../images/theme/backdrop/rotator.php);

Comment: Sorry, I just want to create a new .php file to select images from the directory to put up on a monthly basis.... and ty for your patience... lol

Comment: Adjusted my original post... let me know... Think I am missing something to get the month... either server side or user side...

Comment: Your IF statements need two == because one = just re-sets the value of $month. Why not simplify the code and just do this:
`$image = date('m') .'.jpg';`